# Healthcheck in logstash-http-plugin without authentication

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have configured my logstash with below configuration. With this, I am able to stream logs from cloudfoundry env. But in my case, I want to use a vendor loadbalancer in place for my logstash running in different machines. For which I need to provide them healthcheck url where they poll to get 200 response. Since in my configuration I use basic authentication, the loadbalancer could not validate my healthcheck.

My question is, can I have the basic authentication in place for cloudfoundry application to access my logstash and have a healthcheck end point with same port with any authentication. Please suggest

```html
http{
type => "pcf_logs"
port => MYPORT
user => MYUID
password => MYPWD
ssl => true
keystore => "mykeystore.jks"
keystore_password => "key-pass"
}
```